# Div content floats ok in all browsers but on IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

Please check the following URL:

http://www.deparche.com/registro

You might want to look this:

[image]

In Firefox, Chrome and Safari it looks ok, but on IE10 and Opera it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried several things like targeting the browser with JavaScript and reducing the padding of the input text but it doesn't make any sense. There's enough space to keep the alignment of the fields.

I don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: Having problems with IE performing like any other browser is normal and expected.

Comment: Looks like the second picture in Safari 6.1, Safari Nightly, Chrome 31, Chrome Canary, Opera 17. Basically everything except FF.

Comment: Can you set the width of `lowerSpace` to `281px` as for some reason 100% is not enough for the main div to hold both in one line

Comment: @bjb568 looks fine to me in Chrome 32

Comment: @tilda ?? I thot Chrome 31 was the latest. It says that there are no updates… Maybe only for Windows?

Comment: @bjb568 Maybe only for Windows. Also I checked this page on Safari (for Windows again) and works fine too!

Comment: @tilda Weird… Well, safari for windows is a _bit_ out of date.

Comment: It is always useful to perform a CSS reset first to make sure all browsers start on equal grounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer adds `1px` of right padding to your `input#txtProfilePicPath` element (actually there's 1px padding on every direction by default). Specifying `padding-right: 0` on it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete from `.file-input-wrapper` `float: left;` and `width: 100px;`

Answer (score 0):

To the following selector:

```
div.formElementDiv input[type='text']
```

Add:

```
padding:0 0 0 10px;
```

This explicitly sets all padding to zero (except the padding-left) and fixes your problem.